# How to extract proper string from text by ignoring the special character preceding the string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, numpy

I have couple of text from where I have to extract string followed by specific word but I am facing an issue where the special character(it can be any special character) are preceded by the string.Please correct my regex to get correct result:
Here are some pasted text samples
Sample 1:
`"customer no �123456"`
Sample 2:
`"customer id %9999999"`
Sample 3:
`"customer id 12121212"`
Sample 4:
`"customer id @134563"`

I want the following output of above text samples:
Sample 1 output:
`"123456"`
Sample 2 output:
`"9999999"`
Sample 3 output:
`"12121212"`
Sample 4 output:
`"134563"`

The regex I have used giving wrong output:
`r'\bcustomer\s(?:id|no)\s+(\w+)'`

Please help me correct my regex to get proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\W` to match any non-word char (mostly, any char other than a letter, digit or underscore):

```
r'\bcustomer\s(?:id|no)\W+(\w+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8nXsqF/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `customer` - a string
- `\s` - a whitespace (add `+` after `\s` to match any one or more whitespace chars)
- `(?:id|no)` - `id` or `no` substring
- `\W+` - one or more chars other than word chars (letters/digits/underscores)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.